# CSS: Make background image links in responsive navbar responsive and scale

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, background-image, background-size

Working on a parallax WordPress site for a client and I have a navbar with a sprite being used for the background image for each link. You can see the seven link navbar here (http://www.aishla.com/blog/2014/my-aish-test/). Now it looks great on desktop, but I want to make those images responsive. In other words, get smaller as the design gets smaller.

So I thought I could use the background-size setting in CSS but when I tried in my media query, I get the entire sprite inside of the a href rather than just the portion of the image that I want. So I'm wondering if this is even possible to accomplish this way or if I'm stuck creating a series of sprite for different screen resolutions. Here's an example of what I'm using to try to make this work:

First off the desktop version:

```
nav ul.sub-nav li a { background-image: url("../aish/images/subnav.gif"); background-repeat: no-repeat; color: #000; float: left; height: auto; margin: 0; padding: 80px 0 0 0 ! important; font-size: 16px;font-weight: 700; text-transform: uppercase; text-align: center;  width: 137px; }
nav ul.sub-nav li:first-child a { background-position: 0px 0px; display: inline; }
nav ul.sub-nav li:first-child a:hover { background-position: 0px -140px; }
```

Now the media query fior max-width 768px:

```
nav ul.sub-nav { float: none; width: 763px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; height: auto; list-style-type: none; }
nav ul.sub-nav li a { background-size: 79.562% 79.562%; padding: 80px 0 0 0 ! important; font-size: 14px; width: 109px; }
nav ul.sub-nav li:first-child a { background-position: 0px 0px; display: inline; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry cant comment ->  you cant use background-size: in this way as you are saying that you want your background to be 79.562% of the width of nav ul.sub-nav li a which is set to 137px so that would make your entire sprite 108px wide, hence why it looks so small. if you want nice crisp icons for your nav I would just use .svg images and they will look better on high DPI screens anyway.

If you want to use background-size, you would have to calculate how many times your sprite fits into 137px and you would end up with like >600%, but your sprite would need to be the same ratio as your your div, and all that work to end up with non hdpi images I would not recommend.